# How do I show the built-in integrated calendar in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird 78 contains a built-in calendar. You no longer need the Lightning extension.

When I open Thunderbird 78 in Ubuntu 20.10, I can't find a way to display the calendar. The "Events and Tasks" menu is missing.

Comment: You can also try CTRL SHIFT C.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the calendar icon in the right-hand corner of the top bar. It is hard to find, so hopefully this screenshot will be helpful:

[image: Screenshot]